# Set specific commit of a dependency with govendor

Tags: go, govendor

I'm using govendor for managing dependencies in a project. I have the following dependency in my `vendor/vendor.json`.

```
{
...
"package": [    
    {...},
    {
        "checksumSHA1": "8XAGmXqf+b4LW91wsWxa4kH1NN0=",
        "path": "gopkg.in/h2non/bimg.v1",
        "revision": "9bb3ae10c5ce30e72f7ac0834368536fc095d6a7",
        "revisionTime": "2017-01-13T19:35:42Z"
    }
],
...
```

}

Now I want to use master version of bimg package, which is newer than version 1.0.7 fetched by govendor. What is a proper way to achieve this, beside manually downloading master version from github and saving it to the vendor folder?

ps: all dependencies are committed.

Answer (score 2):

I got help from @jbrandhorst in go slack:

> you'll want to remove the old one as well, `govendor remove gopkg.in/h2non/bimg.v1`
>
> [3:16]   source repo appears to be `github.com/h2non/bimg`, so
>   `govendor fetch github.com/h2non/bimg` will install it to your vendor
>   folder
>
> [3:16]   if you just want to add it to your `vendor.json`, you use
>   `govendor add` I think